# Boostrap 3, three columns, second centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have Bootstrap 3 layout. Content is based on 10 from 12 available columns. Let's say I have something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">LEFT COL</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">CENTER COL</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-1 pull-right">RIGHT COL</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this I have left and right columns positioned as I want it to be - one column width from both, left and right sides of browser window. And I want to position center column exactly in center, between left and right columns, to have same margin between them.

When using offset / pull / push bootstrap classes, they are positioning columns too much left or right.

I have made my own workaround class .col-center which works like .col-lg-offset-1 only I'm using calc() function to subtract the offset in pixels from bootstrap's percentage value. But in my opinion this solution kind of sucks.

Any advice?

**edit:**

[sample image to describe better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pYfo.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Can you not align the content within the columns to get what you're after?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">LEFT COL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">CENTER COL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">RIGHT COL</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In site design I have 3 columns with content. They are pushed by 1 boostrap column from left and right sides of browser (so we have 10 columns spare). Each of those columns is designed as 3 boostrap columns wide, so summed up I have to deal with 9 columns content in 10 columns space.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can't be done in bootstrap. But you can achieve this result by adding a customized class and additional markup. Try if this works for you and breaks nothing :P

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">LEFT COL</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="col-center col-lg-9"> CENTER COL
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-1 pull-right">RIGHT COL</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col-center {
    margin: auto;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: What other two rows? I don't want to use col-lg-4 size since I have page designed for col-lg-3 size.
My solution for now is to add my custom class instead of .col-lg-offset-1:
    .col-center {
        margin-left: calc(8.33% - 65px);
    }
But I try to figure out if there is any "bootstrap way". And I can't use bootstrap 4 with flex layout.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My guess was same, that it's not really possible with pure bootstrap to create. So I took same aproach and I'm using additional class for center column :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add flexbox and distribute the cols evenly.

Comment: As i mentioned in comment, I can't use flexbox in this case. But yes, this is an working option.